# Swift String initializer with Float type Producing Weird Values

Tags: swift

I'm getting weird values when trying to initialize a String with `Swift.Float` types.

```
(lldb) po venue.rating().floatValue.dynamicType
Swift.Float

(lldb) po venue.rating().floatValue
9.2

(lldb) po String(format: "%.1f", [venue.rating().floatValue])
"30746195630460679147717820231031193600.0"

(lldb) po String(format: "%@", [venue.rating().floatValue])
"(\n    \"9.2\"\n)"
```

How would I initialize a `String` with a `Swift.Float` type?

Comment: Remove the square brackets which create an *array* with a single Float element ...

Comment: (lldb) po String(format: "%.1f", venue.rating().floatValue)
"9.2"

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick

Comment: I needed to add the arguments: label to get this to work with an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let someString = "\(someFloat)"
let someString2 = NSString(format: "%.3f", someFloat2)
```

Comment: (lldb) po String(format: "%.1f", "\(venue.rating().floatValue)")
"7274565999564882349472286666024203621660151913392575467285307108824881838408492473663634595489939023400945728880640.0"

Comment: thats not the way to use % in the format argument. You are passing a string.

Comment: The backslash was escaped when I made that last comment